# Right way to handle list items (display and edit)?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

Often we need display items from a list, for example, you can have a few projects, each user could have work on some of those projects, when assign them project, we add projectfirst and then reference them with projectId.

When I started to play with Breezejs and Knockout, I find it is not practical to use dropdown(Select) html element when there are 50+ projects, and it is not right to use Dropdown where you don't let user to change value. So I takes the below code get project name from a projectId

```
  itemName: function (items, item) {
      var r = '';
      if (item() == '') return r;
      var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(getLocal('projects', 'name', true), function (i) {
        return i.id() === item();
      });
      if (match) r = match.name();
      return r;
    }
```

projects is a list of project pre-fetched and stored locally. 
but I found the performance is still not acceptable, javascript was busy, I think the arrayFirst is not efficient enough to search?

Now I let the server side return both projectId and projectName, and display projectName when needed, that looks better, but beside the data redundant, there is another issue when save changes back.

Any suggestion what is the right way to do here?

Thanks

Comment: arrayFirst is a simple for loop over your callback function, it won't be the cause of your issues, especially for only 50 items.  Have you profiled your javascript using your browser's dev tools.

Comment: 70 rows with 370 options, did profiler, javascript was busy.

Comment: Where was it busy ?  Iterating over an array of 370 items is still fast, but executing your callback may not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice; Expose projects data as a [Lookup List](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/lookup-lists)

Then make a request to this list on application launch.

On the users page, load the local project list into an observable `Projects()`

When binding, your select list may look like:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Users -->
  <!--Other fields go here -->
    <select size="10" data-bind="options: $parent.Projects,
                        optionsText: 'name', value: projectId">
                            </select>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

You'll have a scroll-able list of size 10. ( You can make the size 50 as in your case). The value `projectId` is actually the foreign key value of `Users` which will get saved into the database and you won't have to use knockout `arrayFilter` or `arrayFirst` .

Tested on 100+ rows and the performance is satisfactory.

Hope that helps.

Comment: except not sure if the size attribute help here, I did use this way, I have 70 rows, and options list is 370. seems performance was not good enough.